# Looking for the name of an infinite sequence

Tags: prime-numbers, infinite-sequences

I am looking for information about a sequence that seems like it
should converge.  The sequence is textually described as:

```
    The ratio of the integers excluded by each iteration
    of the Sieve of Eratosthenes.
```

So ... the first term would be 1/2 because excluding all the
2s eliminates half the integers (I'm ignoring 0 and 1 ... in
the limit I don't think they matter).  The second term would
be 1/6.  The third term would be 2/30, etc.

Does this sequence have a name?  And is my guess that it converges
correct?

Answer (score 4):

If $p_1<p_2<\cdots$ is the sequence of prime numbers, then the $k$th term in the sequence you describe is
$$
\frac1{p_k} \prod_{j=1}^{k-1} \bigg( 1-\frac1{p_j} \bigg).
$$
This sequence obviously converges to $0$, since $p_k\to\infty$ and the product is less than $1$. In fact, the product itself diverges to $0$: Mertens's theorem says that the product is approximately $1/(e^\gamma\log k)$, where $\gamma$ is Euler's constant. So your sequence is asymptotic to $1/(e^\gamma k\log^2 k)$ by the prime number theorem - a quantitative statement of its convergence to $0$.

Comment: Darn it. I was trying to ask if the *sum* converges.  My bad.

Comment: @Mark: It still converges. Greg showed that your series behaves like $\sum_k 1/(k\log^2 k)$, which converges.

Comment: Wait, not only does this series converge, but it converges to 1 rather trivially since the natural density of the primes is 0, so proportion 1 of the natural numbers are removed at *some* step of the sieve.